# Force convert spaces to tab in all file type

Tags: indentation

So today I'm having some problems with vim. I wanted to use tab when I press the tab key, and a tab is equal to 8 spaces. This is what I added to my /etc/vimrc file:

```
:set noexpandtab
:set tabstop=8
```

It worked, for example .php files . But when I edit .py files, it still convert tab to spaces and use 4 spaces instead of 8 spaces. How to force to use the above setting to all file types?

Comment: You want to configure Filetype plugins. https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.6 Note: There is a reason, why python files why python files expand tabs, see: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim#L117-L120

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's bad practice to edit `/etc/vimrc`, which is likely to not be your user vimrc but the system vimrc (and, unless you are maintaining the system and want to set defaults for everyone using vim on the system, it's not the right thing to modify). Use your personal vimrc instead.

Second, if a particular filetype is not behaving correctly, use filetype-plugins. For example, if you still want <kbd>Tab</kbd> to be a literal tab character, and type the 4 spaces yourself in python:

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim
setlocal noexpandtab softtabstop=8

" make sure to adjust `b:undo_ftplugin`
```

Then (I think) your options are

1. Type the 4 spaces manually;
2. Use `>>` and `<<` (and `>`/`<`/`:[range]>`/`:[range]<`, etc.);
3. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> in insert mode

(This is because Python works best with 4 spaces, though [they are not required](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation).)

Comment: This solved my question after some review. Thank you!